# Whether the formula $\limsup\frac{\max\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}}{a_n}=\limsup\frac{x_n}{a_n}$ holds?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Here, $a_n \uparrow \infty$, $x_n$ is a sequence, it can take negative or positve value. Does the following formula hold? If so, can you provide a proof?
\begin{equation}
\limsup\frac{\max\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}}{a_n}=\limsup\frac{x_n}{a_n}
\end{equation}
It is easy to prove that $limsup\frac{x_n}{a_n}\leq limsup \frac{\max\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}}{a_n}$, since $x_n\leq max\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$. But the other side is hard for me.

This formula doesn't come from any books but from my cognitive snap,so it may not be set up. However, it seems reasonable since the $limsup$ is the max limitation of each sub-sequence. But I cannot proof it in detail.

Thanks in advance for any tips or help in general.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will change my post!

Comment: I am not able to answer the question now, but I will start by asking you what characterization of lim sup have you used.

Comment: Take $a_n = x_n = 1$ for odd $n$ and $a_n = x_n = 2^n$ for even $n$.

Comment: I see! Very, very appreciate for your help!